# Recent Activity tab on each question

Tags: feature-request, recent-activity

Sometimes, I want to check what's happened in the past day on a question I'm interested in. It would be nice to have a "recent activity" tab on each question next to the "oldest", "newest", and "votes" tabs. This tab should bring up a view very similar to the Recent Activity view you can see if you click the envelope next to your name at the top of the page, but containing all the activity on the question thread rather than all the responses to a user.

I'm not sure if this view should include information about when various answers got upvotes/downvotes, but it should make an entry every time somebody posts/edits an answer or makes a comment.

Comment: I made this request many moons ago on UserVoice (https://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/84862-provide-an-answer-sort-based-on-latest-activity), but I'm glad someone brought it up again on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view), where Jeff introduces the timeline feature (Meta only right now).

Comment: Awesome! . . . .