# View questions from all interesting tags into one timeline

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-watching

It would be handy if someone could essentially create a custom questions time line. Ideally it would allow questions from more then one tag to be displayed at once.

For example, if someone's interesting tags include PHP, jQuery, and ecommerce, they can create a time line that show all question tagged with PHP, jQuery, *or* ecommerce. Basically if a question has one of these tags, even if it doesn't have any of the other tags, it will be listed in that users questions time line.

This would make it easier for those of us who only want to follow a specific set of tags. Especially when that number of tags is greater then a handful. Even better when many of those tags get very few questions. It would beat having to open up each tag's timeline every time we log into SO to see if new questions have been asked with that tag.

Comment: You seem to be using "timeline" differently than what it normally means on this site: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view and consider rewording your suggestion?

Comment: See this feature request for that exact thing: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-interesting-questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's possible already:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php+or+jquery+or+ecommerce

Comment: His proposal sounded much more complicated than your solution. I'm not sure if this is what he wants. But we can still point him to the RSS feeds...

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I guess my next question is how would someone know to do this? If I didn't ask this question I would never have figured it out.

Comment: How should c++ be added to this list?  I tried both "java+or+c++" (unsurprisingly doesn't work) and the encoded form "java+or+c%2b%2b", which has the same result.

Comment: @Gareth Stockwell: The encoded form *should* work. But you're right, it doesn't. Please file a bug report for this.

Comment: @balpha: reported: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39201

Comment: @balpha: see Jeff's reply.  If the tag name contains a +, then you need to uses spaces, rather than + symbols, to delimit the tag list in the URL.