# Bug: when passing multiple tags via URL, tags containing '+' are incorrectly parsed

Tags: support, hyperlinks

**Correctly parsed**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+linux

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c++

**Incorrectly parsed**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+c++

*Parsed as 'java' + 'c' + '' + ''*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c+++java

*Parsed as 'c' + '' + '' + 'java'*

Replacing the + characters with the encoded form %2B gives the same result:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+c%2B%2B

*Parsed as 'java' + 'c' + '' + ''*

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2B%2B+java

*Parsed as 'c' + '' + '' + 'java'*

Answer (score 1):

Please use one of the many alternate URL syntaxes.

see:
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

The bare / naked form has inherent limitations.

also, **when combining tags that contain plus, you *must* use space to delimit the tags.** You *cannot* use plus to delimit tags when any tag itself contains a plus. All our internally constructed links already do this for you, so this is only an issue when you manually combine them for whatever reason.