# Where can I give feedback on a new SO feature?

Tags: feature-request

After using SO, for sometimes, I realize that I got some problems.

[Zen masters fighting each other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2505697/how-to-code-feature-on-checking-visitor-ip-address-in-php) on one of my question. Every side have their own arguments and everybody seem right. Frankly, this confuses me: **How can I choose somebody's answer where I don't know the right answer?**

Therefore I would like to propose the feature *I choose this, because* for a user who asked. So at least he/she can explain why he has chosen the particular answer. Maybe it's silly, but as somebody who's getting helps from others' answers, I would like to know everybody get what they deserve. Usually in this kind of situation, I just upvote every good answer and check the one I think the right one.

Second feature:

Every hot question always got plenty answers and comments. If a debate starts among the answerers, it could become hectic. Right now there is only the possibility to sort answers based on **oldest, newest votest**. So, is it possible to make a new sort based on timeline what make comment and answer collide. I believe it will be more easy to read. This feature can only be seen by the person who creates the question, or also for public.

Comment: zen masters don't fight. that's not very zen.

Comment: for me, they were true master ;)

Comment: Oh man, my eyes hurt. Cleaning up this....

Comment: Ok, I tried my best, but I do not understand any of these feature requests. Maybe someone can jump in for a better title. @~quack: DON'T EDIT WHEN I DO IT!

Comment: @lady you can't at-quack, he doesn't have an actual display name set. The lengths people will go to for ASCII characters, I swear...

Comment: @Jeff: I know that. I hope he takes a second look at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "**I choose this because**" feature is already there. Simply write a comment to the answer that you accepted with your reasoning, and possibly also on the answers that you decided not to accept. Also, you can upvote all of the answers which are helpful in solving your problem.

Regarding the "**sort based on timeline what make comment and answer collide**", the feature actually [exists](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2505697/timeline). Do keep in mind, though, that SO is not meant to be Yet Another BB, and dicussion is not really what it is meant for. For the same reason, questions which are likely to spawn much discussion and arguments are usually closed as "subjective and argumentative".

Your question seems to be somewhat special. It sure is a valid technical question, but still a few other users have managed to get them self into into some sort of discussion/dispute. If you feel that someone is "over the line", attacking the other party, please to flag the comment, and a moderator will have a look at it.

Comment: i personally don't mind because the argument is not personal. It stiil on the topic (i think)

Comment: @justjoe: I am happy that the avid zen masters have not succeeded in offending you. I have flagged one of the comments, though, where the one guy is calling the other stupid, without providing any evidence to prove the accusation :)

Comment: thanks and thanks you for give explanation on the culture of SO. Something i really appreciate.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you can use http://meta.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your *second feature* (Btw, it's best to ask separate issues in separate questions), there is a timeline view of your question:

> https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2505697/timeline

See here for more information:

> [Feedback Request: New Timeline Question View](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view)

Comment: thanks i don't know before that this kind of feature exist ;)