# Does Orange Bar also bump me for revision changes in answers on the question I've favorited?

Tags: support, favorites-notifications

I've favorited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983161/code-golf-diamond-pattern) code-golf question for a while, and few minutes ago I got alert about 1 favorite changes in Orange Bar, but when I clicked that there is no new items in my /user/recent/ID?tab=favorite list

So, I've checked all the answers on that question one by one, noticed that [one of the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983161/code-golf-diamond-pattern/2983375#2983375) got edited and got a new revision.

So Orange Bar should not bump me for the revision changes OR /user/recent/ID?tab=favorite should show me changes on that question?

**Edit**: I think my question was not clear. I wanted to mentioned that I cannot reach the target question through the notification bar, because when I clicked the bar, recent activity list does not show me the question at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check all the answers one by one, just click the date under "Latest Activity" in the sidebar and it'll take you to the thing that changed last.

Or of course use the [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view)..

Comment: Imm, I think my question not clear. I meant that I don't see the target question at all in [my recent favorite changes list](http://stackoverflow.com/users/recent/213464?Tab=Favorites&StartDate=2010-06-06&EndDate=2010-06-11), last one was 1 day ago, but I got notification few minutes ago. Since I only have one favorite now, I can figure out its on that question.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. About once a week I'll log in, the "You have 1 favorite change. See your favorites." bar will pop up, with a helpful link that takes me to a page... that doesn't show me what has changed. Is it possible to have the link in the bar take me to a page that shows the change that triggered the notification? Without me having to root around to find it?