# Votes Count Breakdown Reconstruction Script

Tags: discussion, voting, privileges, timeline

When i heard about the [timeline page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54366/feedback-request-newer-timeline-question-view) which is rather unknown (well, there is no link to it) i thought it would be fun to write a script which gets all the votes from there and mimics the [view vote counts priviledge.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/view-vote-counts)

Yesterday i got around to doing this and it works *really* well (*until the year 10000 at least*). Now i've got two questions:

- What is the database load associated with accessing the timeline? (As i read that one of the reasons for this to be a priviledge is that the necessessary queries are time-consuming)
- Am i right in assuming that i should *not* post my script on [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/)?

**Edit:** As of now the script can be found [here](https://stackapps.com/questions/2916/show-post-score-breakdown-early-script)...

Answer (score 1):

Please post your script to StackApps. [There is already a script that does something similar](https://stackapps.com/questions/557/votecounts-bookmarklet-to-display-up-down-votes-even-for-rep1k). It uses data from the API though instead.

This feature currently isn't supplied to every user through the normal interface because the database lookup is too costly to get that information for every user.

But, for regular users of the site who want to see vote splits but are sub 1k rep, I think your script would be very helpful.

Comment: Of course it would be useful, that's why i wrote it but i somewhat doubt that database loopup associated with the timeline page is less severe. Of course there are probably not that many people who would even know about this script, just as there are not that many people who know about the timeline itself.

Comment: @H.B. "Of course there are probably not that many people who would even know about this script" - that is the reason why your script is just fine.  The number of people that would use your script is orders of magnitude (~5) smaller than the number of users that hit stackoverflow daily through Google.