# Is there a viewable history for edited questions?

Tags: discussion, off-topic

How can I determine if a question is off-topic or ***if through editing by a third-party*** was made off-topic? Unless, there is some way to see what the edits were, this seems problematic.

Comment: No doubt I couldn't find this due to my lack of Wiki experience. If this is a duplicate answer, someone please link to the original and close this. Thankyou Peter and @Gareth for your quick replies. I did search under revision and didn't see an obvious answer, but far too many questions were returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Post revisions

When you click the "edited ..." link...

[image]

you'll get to the "Revisions" page, which shows every revision that was created by users editing the post, automated Community actions or other events like questions being closed or locked.

The page is also available by appending `/revisions` to the URL. For example: `https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100961/revisions`

---

#### Timeline

There is also a more specific timeline, which allows you to inspect *which actions* happened *when*. It contains much more information than just the post revisions.

To access a timeline, you have to manually enter the URL: `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/100961/timeline`. Notice the "posts" instead of "question".

[image]

See this question for more information: [Feedback Request: New Timeline Question View](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view)

Comment: That timeline is such a great feature. It should really be a first-class citizen—rather than a URL hack—on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You can view the history of the revisions to a post.

If a post has been edited, there will be a footnote on the post saying when it was edited and who edited that you can click on. Alternatively, you can change the URL of a post to view the revision history.

For example, this is the revision history for this question:

[`https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/100961/revisions`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/100961/revisions)