# Is there a way to see who reopened a question and who had previously closed it?

Tags: support, closed-questions, reopened-questions

When a question gets closed, it shows who closed it; if a question gets reopened, it no longer shows who closed it, nor does it show who reopened it.  Is there any way to see who reopened it and/or who closed it previously?

The particular example I was looking at is [Optimization practice dealing with points on a line](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/140651/72).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/140651/revisions - for your convenience :)

Comment: @ChrisF: Thanks.  I already installed the userscript you linked to in your answer.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can see the history of a post by following the link:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/posts/[PostId]/revisions
```

This will be available via the time on the last edited flair:

[image: Where to get the revisions]

If there's no last editor you can type the URL yourself, or there is a [StackApp](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a) which will add a "history" link to all posts.

Answer (score 3):

This information is also available via the [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/295232) feature. While there is no direct link to the timeline (unless you use a userscript), it can be constructed quite easily: host name + `/posts/` + ID of the question + `/timeline`.

For this particular question, the URL is https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/140651/timeline

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check the revision history.

`http://<site>/posts/<post id>/revisions`

If the question has been edited, click the "edited xyz" link:

[image]

I can't find any reopened questions, but https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/194/revisions shows the name of the closers--so I guess the usernames of repoeners will be visible as well.