# Number of views per day of a question, from creation to the present

Tags: feature-request, questions, views, timeline

I'd like to be able to visualise how many views per day a particular question got, day after day, since it was posted to present day. (I recently posted [this question](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3484/timeline-of-a-questions-views) on meta TeX.SE, but got no reply.)

I know of [this old post by Jeff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view), but that's not what I'm after. I'm rather thinking of something similar to a user's reputation timeline (available on his/her profile page), only showing the number of views per day of a given question.

As far as I know, no existing query is designed to generate such a timeline.

Is such a feature available somewhere on the site? Does it work for all SE sites?

If not, would such a feature be difficult to implement? Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK views are only stored cumulatively, not individually, so this timeline may not be technically feasiblye

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks! I didn't know of the question you linked to. I guess you can close mine as a duplicate. It's too bad such a feature is not available; it would have been great to visualise the activity associated with a given question.

Comment: @Jubobs cheers. Meta is so big that nobody can know all questions ever posted. :) Can't close your question, one vote is all I got, need 4 more users or 1 mod. :)