# How can I check for the last activities on a given questions?

Tags: support, user-interface, timeline

I'm interested in answering a question. But my answer still isn't ready. I added the question to my favourites. I also got some messages (mostly answers to my comments? ...I'm not sure...) However, I visit the question day by day as to check for new answers, edits, or comments, but I am still not sure if I missed some important update...

Now I wonder if there might be a built-in function, that displays the activity or history for a question?

### After some further research...

...I found that there is the [**timeline** function](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/36303/238205). But I could not find a direct link to it on the SO question, whereas a little "URL hacking" made it accessible to me. Is there an easier **way to access it?**

Comment: [Yes](http://stackapps.com/questions/4148/view-post-timeline). Possibly. Depending on how easy setting up userscripts is. Not something I've tried.

Comment: Touché! You can't access it from the standard website without URL hacking - :-(.

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for the hint. I found [SE Modifications — Username autocomplete in comments, inline revision source, and utility links](http://stackapps.com/q/2138/24175) ...and now I'm looking for a how-to for installing user scripts ;)

Comment: ...here is what I found for Firefox: [Easy Way To Add User Script in Firefox | Ooiks's Blog](http://ooiks.com/blog/uncategorized/easy-way-to-add-user-script-in-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way *my way* to get it to work on Firefox.

- install [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)
- install [SE Modifications](https://stackapps.com/questions/2138/se-modifications-username-autocomplete-in-comments-inline-revision-source-a)

  - follow the `install / update script` link in the Download section

Big thanks to

- Ooi Keng Siang for [Easy Way To Add User Script in Firefox](http://ooiks.com/blog/uncategorized/easy-way-to-add-user-script-in-firefox)
- Anthony Lieuallen, Aaron Boodman, Johan Sundström (et al.) for *Greasemonkey*
- Rebecca Chernoff, Yi Jiang, and Tim Stone for *SE Modifications*

Comment: Even if *my problem* is solved now, I'll be happy to accept better answers than mine :)