# How can I see whether a question has been previously closed?

Tags: support, closed-questions

How can I see whether a question has been previously closed?

It used to be visible in the question edit history, before the [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/178179) took place.

I don't see any 'edited' link underneath the post, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58898712/395857) (the question was closed for a few hours before being reopened):

[image]

Comment: The post [timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36303/feedback-request-new-timeline-question-view).

Comment: @yivi thanks! (example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58898712/timeline)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's still visible in both the timeline and the revision history of a post.

#### Revision history

The revision history can be reached by clicking the 'edited' link underneath the post:

[image]

If the post isn't edited yet, there's no such link, and you have to construct it yourself: `https://[SITE URL]/posts/[POST ID]/revisions`. Example: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/549/revisions. (By the way, that's not caused by the new post notice rollout; it has been that way for as long as I can remember.)

[image]

#### Timeline

The timeline link was hidden [on purpose](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126447/295232) but it's now [readily visible](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/342316/295232):

[image]

It will lead you to a URL like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/549/timeline
Sometimes you need to scroll through a lot of daily vote summaries, but you'll find an entry like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I don't see any `edited` link underneath the post,  see example I added in the question.

Comment: Right; if it has no revisions, you'll have to construct that URL manually as well.

Comment: Got it, that seems to be new since the introduction of the [New Post Notices rollout on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337013/178179).

Comment: No, @FranckDernoncourt, that has always been the case. If a post hasn't been edited there's no link to the revisions (because why would there be, if there's only one revision, the current? That for questions it's useful to see previous closures or bounties probably came after the initial design decision.).

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for the correction, sorry I must have mistremembered then.

Answer (score 3):

You can view the information by clicking on the "Timeline" icon:

[image]

which displays:

[image]