# Is it possible to get info about where my link was published and where the traffic comes from?

Tags: support, publicity-badges

This morning I got the 25-view announcer bronze badge for a question on Arqade. It was a pleasant surprise, since I think the code I wrote for Kittens Game automation was pretty neat and I'm glad that people seem to enjoy it.

But then I noticed I got a hat. So I looked at the hat, and it said I had a gold badge! So I went to my network profile and, all in the span of 24 hours, I got the bronze, silver, and gold badges for sharing the link of a post. Wow, this is fascinating, I thought.

It is certainly odd for a link of mine to get 1,000 clicks in a single day! It would be really good to know where these clicks came from. Surely the browsers that click in have some referer data or something.

Is it at all possible to investigate the source of these clicks? Because I haven't posted anything recently, so clearly someone else has shared something that has my referral code in the URL, and I'd really like to see where that is!

Comment: Its not in a single day - its an aggregate but the query was fixed recently - [see this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339664/missing-publicist-badge) for more details.

Comment: You would have shared the link yourself, the badges use your user number in the share link to credit you with the badge.

Comment: This question is really twofold: why and where. The *why* is answered elsewhere, changed the way it works and recalculated. The **where** isn't disclosed, it would be neat if we could know the referrers.

Comment: @Catija For sure I'm the one that posted the link. But as I said, someone has clearly shared something that had my referral code in it. For example, I tell someone hey I have code for that! I pass them a share link. They then bookmark it (with my number because they didn't think about it) and then share it somewhere else. Then that person's post goes viral. However, it looks like there is no unicorn post to find, it's definitely a result of the now-fixed query, plus five years of steady sharing...

Comment: @Rob Wouldn't it though? I mean, if I knew where people were following links from, I'd promote there more, probably...

Comment: Ah, well... if you don’t know... I’m gonna guess that it’s not info we share. I don’t actually know how to look at referrers for a specific post... probably because I don’t have access to those tools myself.

Comment: The [Google Analytics Help](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/2382957?hl=en) explains the term. Some [places hide](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/89988/93353) the details. It's easy to [get your referer URL](https://www.whatismyreferer.com/), and since the system keeps enough on record to uniquely compare them it's easy to show the top ten. It *could* look something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hOEv7.png

Comment: Somewhat related is https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/340064/248000 (but of course, not exactly)

Comment: @Rob when I go to that page I do not see any of those links you have in your screenshot...

Comment: Heh, I just got badges for questions I'm pretty sure I never shared. So this would be nice, definitely.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: You shared the link to your answer in a comment that was deleted from the site, but copied into a clone of Arqade!

---

Checking [your profile in Arqade](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1413/corsika) I went through the [Publicist badge you earned](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/badges/191/publicist?userid=1413). There it states that is for [the answer you posted](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038) on the question [What do kittens use gold for?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/185025).

This means the badge was awarded for sharing your answer with your ID.

Since the share link to the answer is:

```
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038
```

And your ID in the site is:

```
1413
```

It means that the link that got 1000+ clicks was:

```
https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038/1413
```

So now it is a matter of googling that link and seeing what happens... [and there we go](https://www.google.com/search?q=https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038/1413)! Apparently there is a forum that copies the content from Stack Exchange and has this very question in https://gaming.stackovernet.com/de/q/44217, among others. Funny thing is that it keeps record of a comment you left to the accepted answer, while it is deleted now in Arqade.SE. There you said:

> I get all my blueprints through my [trades with the Zebras](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/185038/1413). – corsiKa 25 sep. 14

And apparently many people clicked it. So it was you who commented, indeed!

<sub>Funny thing is that another comment there, with more upvotes, says:</sub>

> <sub>@Damek It's always 10%, though if a hostile race refuses to trade at all, then it never even tries to check for blueprints this trade. See [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/184416/50582) for more. – Billy Mailman 25 sep. 14</sub>

<sub>And [the user with the ID 50582 does not have any Publicist badge](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/50582/billy-mailman?tab=badges&sort=class).</sub>