# Why did my question get a ton of views in 2 days?

Tags: discussion, hot-questions

I recently asked my first [question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132815/how-do-i-turn-a-2d-coin-texture-to-a-3d-image/132833?noredirect=1#comment197721_132833) on the Graphic Design Community and got some great answers.

To my surprise, within a day it said that it had 2k views. Now it has 4k, which is a ton. Before most of my questions that I asked on SO got 50-100 views, the highest was ~450.

Was there something that I said that made a difference? Is there a way I could see if it was "Featured"? Is this just a thing that happens by random chance?

Comment: FYI, a fairly closely related question is [Is there a way to determine how/why when one of my posts on a network site suddenly starts getting unusual traction?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/340064/is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-why-when-one-of-my-posts-on-a-network-site-sudde).

Comment: @JohnOmielan, thanks for the similar question. Didn't come up when I searched for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you look at the [timeline](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/132815/timeline) of your question, you can see that it became a Hot Network Question, and it was tweeted. Both of these are things that tend to increase views on questions, as the question is now exposed to many other people besides the core users of the site.

[image: Screenshot of timeline]

Comment: Thanks! Never even knew that the timeline was a thing!

Comment: @JackStoller [It's pretty well hidden.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126447/add-a-link-to-the-timeline-of-a-post)

Answer (score 4):

I am assuming that your question must have appeared under Hot Network Questions in the right-hand sidebar.

To try and work out why it reached there you could review [What are the criteria for questions to be selected for Hot Network Questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60756/what-are-the-criteria-for-questions-to-be-selected-for-hot-network-questions)

Comment: Thank you for the link, it's very useful. Because Alex had the timeline that showed that it did, I accepted it over yours. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @JackStoller My answer only complements Alex's so I think you clicked Accept wisely.